# transformation of $y=3(4-x)^3-6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am looking for the expansion of $y=3(4-x)^3-6$.

I got confused about the $(4-x) $ part. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to expand the right-hand side into powers of $x$? At the moment your question is rather unclear.

Comment: Exponentiation before multiplication. $(4-x)^3 = 4^3 - 3\times 4^2x + 3\times 4x^2 -x^3$

Comment: sorry guys dk why the answer was asking for the transformation of that function, thanks for the help, I still dk how to state the transformation after expand it..

Answer (score 1):

$$3(4-x)^3-6$$
$$= 3[(4-x)(4-x)(4-x)]-6$$
$$= 3[(16-8x+x^2)(4-x)]-6$$
$$=3[64-48x+12x^2-x^3]-6$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: should I keep expanding?

Comment: @sh woo First distrubute the 3, then subtract 6 from the end result and reorder the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're confused about the $(4-x)$ part, let's forget the rest for now and focus on that.

$(4-x)^{3}=(4-x)(4-x)(4-x)$

$(4-x)(4-x)$ = $x^{2}-8x+16$=$(4-x)^{2}$

We have expanded $(4-x)^{2}$ so far, we just need to multiply this by $(4-x)$ in order to get $(4-x)^{3}$

$$(x^{2}-8x+16)(4-x)= (4-x)^{3}$$

```
       After you've done the above , multiply the answer by 3 and then subtract 6 from it.
```